# Change head of the remote branch to latest commit

Tags: git

Currently, Head pointer in remote branch is set to one commit before the latest commit.

```
git log 
commit2 f536ca3cd
commit1 29000d355
```

commit2 is the latest commit,

in local branch : "saurabh" HEAD is at commit2
but in remote branch "origin/saurabh" HEAD is at commit1

How to set HEAD to latest commit in remote branch?

This is not working

```
git rebase origin/saurabh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added "commit2" to your local branch, then the way to get it to the remote branch is with git push

A typical use would look like this:

git push origin *name-of-branch*